# Simple jQuery animation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

can anyone help me fix this, what am I missing?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

  $('#loginButton').click(function() {
     $('#toplogin').animate({
       height: '0px'
     });
  });
</script>
```

The `onClick` doesn't even execute!

The div I want the `onClick` event to work on is here:

```
 <div id="loginButton"><a href="#" title="login">Login &raquo;</a></div>
```

The div I want the animation to affect is here:

```
div id="toplogin"> <!-- more stuff -->  </div>
```

Comment: You don't need that semi-colon after the height line inside the object.  Otherwise looks alright, are you sure the `.click()` is being fired?  Do you definitely have elements with those IDs?  Is there CSS causing problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$('#loginButton').click(function() {
    $('#toplogin').animate({
        height: 0
    },
    function() {
        $(this).css('display', 'none');
    });
});
```

Comment: @user775736 i tested and the code is not working. this may work. i also set the `height: 0px` to that `div` using css and it does not hide the content.why this i don't know. if anybody has any suggestion please share.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the semicolon after `height: '0px'` to make your JavaScript valid.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#loginButton').click(function() {
     $('#toplogin').animate({ height:'0px' });
  });
</script>
```

However, unless you have `overflow:hidden` set for `#toplogin` the element will still be visible, even though it's height is `0px`. An easier way is just using `slideUp()`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#loginButton').click(function(){ $('#toplogin').slideUp(); });
</script>
```

Comment: This should work ... it doesn't work only if from css you're hiding the element.

Comment: @user775736: Added extra information to answer as to the cause for it seeming not to work.

Answer (score 0):

you should wrap your code in following construction to make it valid as jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    your code;
})
```